Formating a float/double to scientific notation or Si units
I am trying to make a seemingly simple piece of code that I am unable to get working.
It takes a double (or float) and formats it to a string in a specific way: E.g. 13.453.123,25 (Dots for thousands, commas for fractions? decimals? obligatory English not my first language etc...)
SI units "J: 13,453M" or Scientific "J: 1,345E6" Either is fine, although my preference is SI units. This string is going to be put on a tiny I2C 0,96" display so it must be 10 chars wide. I am making a joulemeter with an Arduino Nano and I want to have a tally showing currently  used energy on the display. And the actual accurate data will be stored on a uSD card.
I tried dtostre() and sprintf() but every time it would break the string. Dtostre() did work in a Serial.println() but not when trying to get it in a string.
Anyway here is my code so far:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define Pin_Enable 2
#define Pin_Red 11
#define Pin_Green 12
#define Pin_Blue 13
#define Timer_Prefill 59285   // 59285 100ms  Set Timer PreFill = 65 535 - (16*10^6 * 0.1 sec / 256)     TCNTn = 65535 - ( ( 16*10^6 x intervaltime in sec ) / Pre_Scaler Value ) =  
bool Running = false;
bool Write = false;
uint32_t Previous_Time = 0;
uint16_t Current = 0;
uint16_t Voltage = 0;
uint8_t Count = 0;
float Energy = 0;

Adafruit_SSD1306 Display(128, 64, &Wire, -1);

void setup() {
  // <> Setup Hardware Timer <>                                                 // https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-timer-tutorial 2023-04-13
  noInterrupts();                                                               // Turn off interrupts during adjusting settings
  TCCR1A = 0;                                                                   // Initialize the Timer
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1 = Timer_Prefill;                                                        // Prefill Timer
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);                                                        // Set the pre scaler to 256
  interrupts();                                                                 // Turn on interrruptsDisplay
  // </> Setup Hardware Timer </>  

  // <> Setup Pins <>
  pinMode(Pin_Enable, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pin_Enable), Recording, CHANGE);
  pinMode(Pin_Red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin_Green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin_Blue, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Pin_Green, HIGH);
  // </> Setup Pins </>
  

  displayString.reserve(15); // to avoid fragmenting memory when using String
  Display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C); //0x78 / 0x3C
  delay(2000);
  Display.setTextSize(2);
  Display.setTextColor(WHITE); // text color
  Display.setCursor(0, 10);    // position to displ
  DisplayWrite("Joulemeter REDACTED");
  delay(5000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if(Write) {
    Add_Record();
    Write = false;
  }
}

void DisplayWrite(String text) {
  int16_t x1;
  int16_t y1;
  uint16_t width;
  uint16_t height;

  Display.getTextBounds(text, 0, 0, &x1, &y1, &width, &height);
  Display.clearDisplay(); // clear Display
  Display.setCursor((128 - width) / 2, (64 - height) / 2);
  Display.println(text); // text to Display
  Display.display();
}

void Recording(){                                                               // Gets called everytime the button changes state.
  if (Previous_Time + 250 < millis()) {                                         // Check if atleast 250ms have passed since last changed. This is to filter out switch bounces.
    Previous_Time = millis();                                                   // Store the current time to Previous_Time for the next press.
    Running = !Running;                                                         // Toggle Running.    
                                                                                
    if (Running) {                                                              // Start recording 
      noInterrupts();
      TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);                                                   // Turn on timer interrupts (Enable timer)
      TCNT1 = Timer_Prefill;                                                    // Prefill the timer
      interrupts();
      digitalWrite(Pin_Green, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin_Red, HIGH);                                                             
      Serial.println("Started");
    } else {                                                                    // Stop recording
      Serial.println("Stopping");
    }  
  } 
}

String MakeXLong(String Text, uint8_t Length) {
  while(Text.length() < Length) {
    Text = "0" + Text;
  }
  return Text;
}

void Add_Record(){
  Count++;
  digitalWrite(Pin_Blue, HIGH);
  Voltage = map(analogRead(A0), 0, 1023, 0, 60000);
  Current = map(analogRead(A1), 0, 1023, 0, 65000);                                
  Energy += Voltage * Current * 0.1 * 0.001 * 0.001;
    
  if (Count >= 10) {
    // <> Generate Output <>
    String Temp_A = MakeXLong(String(Voltage), 5);
    String Temp_B = MakeXLong(String(Current), 5);

    String Disp_Text = "";
    Disp_Text += "V: " + String(Temp_A[0]) + String(Temp_A[1]) + "," + String(Temp_A[2]) + String(Temp_A[3]) + String(Temp_A[4]) + " ";
    Disp_Text += "A: " + String(Temp_B[0]) + String(Temp_B[1]) + "," + String(Temp_B[2]) + String(Temp_B[3]) + String(Temp_B[4]) + " ";
    Disp_Text += "J: "; 

    // </> Generate Output </>

    // <> Display Output <>
    DisplayWrite(Disp_Text);
    Serial.println("Next");
    Serial.println("R: " + String(Voltage) + " - " + String(Current) + " - " + String(Energy));

    // </> Display Output </>
    Count = 0;
  }
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(Pin_Blue, LOW);
}

// <> Timer Interrupt Service Routine <>
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
  TCNT1 = Timer_Prefill;                                                        // Prefill the timer
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN) ^ 1);                      // Toggle the build in led
  
  // <> Code to be executed <>
  Write = true;

  if (!Running) {
    noInterrupts();
    TIMSK1 &= !(1 << TOIE1);                                                    // Turn off timer interrupts (Disable timer)
    interrupts();
    digitalWrite(Pin_Green, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Pin_Red, LOW);
    Serial.println("Stopped");
  }
  // </> Code to be executed </> 
}
//</> Timer Interrupt Service Routine </>


If you need more info or anything else, feel free to ask!
EDIT:
I managed to get it working on a online compiler (yay w3schools.com)
Si Units: (Not safe yet just prove of concept)
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double Energy = 14999.25;
  uint8_t Si_Count = 0;
  char Si[] = {' ', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'Z'};
  while (Energy > 1000) {
    Si_Count++;
    Energy /= 1000;
  }
  string Output = to_string((int)Energy) + Si[Si_Count];
  cout << Output;
}

Scientific:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  float Energy = 14999.25;
  char Buffer [8];
  sprintf(Buffer, "%.1E", Energy);
  string Output = "J: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    Output += Buffer[i];
  }
  cout << Output;
  return 0;
}

Now I've got to wait till tonight when I can test it on my Arduino.

Out of curiosity, can you have 1.36E-3 milliAmps?  This is combining Scientific Notation with SI units.  Or more explicit:3.14E-5 meters?

Yes.  That would be the same as saying 136 microamps.  SI units are literally designed for use with scientific notation.

What type of Arduino are you using?  Some boards don't support floats in sprintf and some do.

@Delta_G Arduino Nano

On the nano the support for floating points is turned off in sprintf.  You'll have to use dtostre to do it right.

This is not quite what I want, but close enough and it works!
String Fomat_Si(double Input){
  uint8_t Si_Count = 0;
  char Si[] = {' ', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'Z'};
  while (Input > 1000) {
    Si_Count++;
    Intput /= 1000;
  }
  return "J: " + String(Input) + Si[Si_Count];
}

